# Is there event generated on opening application?

Tags: android

is there any event generated on opening applications in Android.

Scenario:

User opens app list -> opens application << EVENT GENERATED >> -> user application view

If such event exists, could you register for it?

Answer (score 0):

In your base activity:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ... do whatever here
}
```

Comment: Not for my own, but watching for other applications being opened by user.